# Switch default is not showing when it should

Tags: c, switch-statement

In my C program which is using switch I have problem with my int variable.
My code is:

```
while(1) {
    printf("0. END\n1. TRANSLATE\n2. TEST FROM LESSON\n3. RANDOM"
            " WORDS TEST\n4. SHOW DICTIONARY\n5. ADD WORD\n"
            "6. DELETE WORD\nYOUR CHOICE: ");
    
    scanf("%d",&option);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n");

    switch(option) {
        case 0: {
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        
        case 1: {
            system("cls");
            translate();
            printf("\n");

            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            system("cls");
            lessons();
            printf("\n");
            
            break;
        }

        case 3: {
            randomFromLessons();
            printf("\n");
            
            break;
        }

        case 4: {
            system("cls");
            allWords();
            printf("\n");
            
            break;
        }

        case 5: {
            system("cls");
            addWord();

            break;
        }
        
        case 6: {
            system("cls");
            deleteWord();
            printf("\n");
            
            break;
        }
        
        default: {
            printf("---------------\n");
            printf("WRONG VALUE.\n");
            printf("---------------\n\n");
        }   
    }
    
}
```

When I type 'd' into option var. it shows default, which is what I want, BUT when I press number 1 which starts method named "translate()" and then get back into main menu and press 'd' again it gets me back into "translate()" instead of showing the default.

When I use char instead of int, there is no problem.
So, what exactly is the problem? What keeps happening? What am I doing wrong? Isn't using char in switch the best option overall then?

Comment: you switch case tests against integers, not characters.
when you enter `1` it is actually `'1'`, i.e. a character

Comment: @Raildex: That's not the problem here, because the integer is canned with the `%d` format, so it really is an integer value.

Comment: Scanning variables with `%d` may fail if you enter something that is not a number, such as just "d". In that case, the input stream is set back to where scanning began and you end up scanning the wrong input all over again. `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions or `EOF`. Check the return value. You can skip over invalid input by scanning  a word without storing it with the `%*s` format.

Comment: @MOehm I see, so if I understand correctly. When I pressed 1 for translate() method and then 'd' in main menu, scanf() instead of using the 'd' used previous input which was the number 1. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, `scanf()` cannot scan a number, so it resets the "reading pointer" and leaves `d` alone. You need to check the result of `scanf()`, please read its documentation. You should always read the documentation of functions you call. ;-)

Comment: don't use fflush(stdin) it is UB, instead use fgets/sscanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to allow text input, you should read the input as a string with `fgets` and then convert to integers as needed.

If you only wish to accept numbers, you should check the result of `scanf` to see if it succeeded - in this case it will return `1` when successful, in case it managed to read 1 parameter. If not successful, it won't overwrite `option` but keep the previous value - that's why you get the behavior you describe.

Furthermore `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior since `fflush` was never meant to be used on input streams. To just discard the line feed character from stdin you can add single `getchar()`.

So you could fix the code into something like this:

```
int result;

while(1)
{
  result = scanf("%d",&option);
  getchar();
  if(result == 1)
    break;
  else
    printf("some error message\n");
}

switch(option)
...
```